# Quantum physics and wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This is about sketching a one-dimensional probability distribution of $P(x)$ and $P(y)$. I am looking for two wavefunctions, one that is Separable and one that isn't, but yet have the same $P(x)$ and $P(y)$. I am confused on how to start this problem. Any help would be amazing.

$$P(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,y)|^2 dy$$
$$P(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Psi(x,y)|^2 dx$$

Comment: To start the problem you need to give the potential $V$ which is present in the region. From this we can solve the Schrodinger equation and find $\psi(x,y)$.

Comment: What about $\Psi(x,y)=\psi_n(x)\psi_n(y)$ where $\psi_n(\beta)$ are any solution to your problem?

Comment: Psi(x,y)=(2/a)Sin((n_x Pi x/a)(Sin((n_y Pi y/a))) That is what the book says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with quantum mechanics - it's just a feature of bivariate distributions.

As a simple example, a distribution like this one is separable,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but if you cut out two of the peaks and put their probability in the initial ones, you get a distribution that's correlated (and therefore not separable) but which still has the same marginal distributions.

[image]

Implementing that in a quantum mechanical context is up to you (I would use wavefunctions of the form $\psi(x,y) \propto \exp(-a(x^2+y^2) +b xy)$, but that's just my personal taste) and rather out of scope of our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714).